# Problem receiving Javascript / axios callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am relatively new to JavaScript and seems to have a problem getting success/error callback functions to work while using Axios.

For example, running the following integration test code using jest (npm test command), I get the output listed below. I am wondering why the message 'my-ping-2 success.' or 'my-ping-3 error: ...' are not being printed on the console. I am trying to make sure that the caller of the inner functions can optionally pass-in callback functions for success and error situations. What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!!

Details:
I know that the local API server works fine, it returns HTTP status 200 if I visit URL http://localhost:9090/api/v1/ping and tests via Postman. I have listed the full source code below that can reproduce the problem on my machine (MacOS, nodejs version v12.16.1,  npm version 6.13.4).

I am using the generic axios(config) method in the inner function because I am using the same inner function for HTTP get/post calls. I hope that is OK.

jest console output

```
 PASS  src/__tests__/01_my.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log src/__tests__/01_my.test.js:14
      my-ping-1...
    console.log src/__tests__/01_my.test.js:20
      my-ping-4 done.
```

Source code for reproduction of problem

```
import axios from "axios";
import { isEmpty, merge } from 'lodash';

const baseURL = 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/';
const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
};
const source = axios.CancelToken.source();


test('Test my-appcode', done => {

    console.log('my-ping-1...');
    fw_get_1('/ping',  function(response) {
        console.log('my-ping-2 success.');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('my-ping-3 error: ' + fw_jsonFormatter(error));
    } );
    console.log('my-ping-4 done.');

    done();
});

function fw_get_1(url, successCallback = null,
                       errorCallback = null) {
    return fw_get_2(url, {}, successCallback, errorCallback);
}

function fw_get_2(url, configs = {},
                                successCallback = null,
                                errorCallback = null) {
    url = encodeURI(url);
    return fw_request_3('get', url, configs, successCallback, errorCallback);
}

function fw_request_3(method, url, configs = {},
                             successCallback = null,
                             errorCallback = null) {

    let inputCfgs = {
        params: configs.params,
        data : configs.data,
        headers : configs.headers
    };

    const axiosOptions = merge(
        {},
        {
            method,
            url,
            baseURL,
            headers,
            cancelToken: source.token
        },
        inputCfgs
    );

    return axios(axiosOptions).then( function(response) {
        if (successCallback) {
            console.log('fw_request_internal success-1 method: ' + axiosOptions.method + ' url: ' + axiosOptions.url);
            successCallback(response);
        } else {
            console.log('fw_request_internal success-2 method: ' + axiosOptions.method + ' url: ' + axiosOptions.url);
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (errorCallback) {
            console.log('Calling input errorCallback method: ' + axiosOptions.method + ' url: ' + axiosOptions.url +  fw_jsonFormatter(error));
            errorCallback(error);
        } else {
            console.log('fw_request_internal error-2 method: ' + axiosOptions.method + ' url: ' + axiosOptions.url);
            console.log(fw_jsonFormatter(error));
        }
    });
}

function fw_jsonFormatter(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who saw similar problem, it looks like the issue was that the test harness finished running before the callbacks could be called. I added a wait for a few seconds at the end of the test to confirm and now I am able to see all the console logs as expected.  See the revised code below.   I am writing some JS wrapper functions around REST APIs. Just want to make sure that the users of the wrapper functions can optionally override the callback functions. Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.  Thank you!!

New console log

```
 PASS  src/__tests__/01_my.test.js (5.722s)
  ● Console

    console.log src/__tests__/01_my.test.js:14
      my-ping-1...
    console.log src/__tests__/01_my.test.js:20
      my-ping-4 done.
    console.log src/__tests__/01_my.test.js:61
      fw_request_internal success-1 method: get url: /ping
    console.log src/__tests__/01_my.test.js:16
      my-ping-2 success.
    console.log src/__tests__/01_my.test.js:83
      Waited 4 seconds
    console.log src/__tests__/01_my.test.js:84
      Finished test wait
```

Revised source code with wait at the end of tests.

```
import axios from "axios";
import {merge } from 'lodash';

const baseURL = 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/';
const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
};
const source = axios.CancelToken.source();


test('Test my-appcode', done => {

    console.log('my-ping-1...');
    fw_get_1('/ping',  function(response) {
        console.log('my-ping-2 success.');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('my-ping-3 error: ' + fw_jsonFormatter(error));
    } );
    console.log('my-ping-4 done.');

    fw_test_end_wait(done, 'Finished test wait', 4 );
});

function fw_get_1(url, successCallback = null,
                       errorCallback = null) {
    return fw_get_2(url, {}, successCallback, errorCallback);
}

function fw_get_2(url, configs = {},
                                successCallback = null,
                                errorCallback = null) {
    url = encodeURI(url);
    return fw_request_3('get', url, configs, successCallback, errorCallback);
}

function fw_request_3(method, url, configs = {},
                             successCallback = null,
                             errorCallback = null) {

    let inputCfgs = {
        params: configs.params,
        data : configs.data,
        headers : configs.headers
    };

    const axiosOptions = merge(
        {},
        {
            method,
            url,
            baseURL,
            headers,
            cancelToken: source.token
        },
        inputCfgs
    );

    return axios(axiosOptions).then( function(response) {
        if (successCallback) {
            console.log('fw_request_internal success-1 method: ' + axiosOptions.method + ' url: ' + axiosOptions.url);
            successCallback(response);
        } else {
            console.log('fw_request_internal success-2 method: ' + axiosOptions.method + ' url: ' + axiosOptions.url);
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (errorCallback) {
            console.log('Calling input errorCallback method: ' + axiosOptions.method + ' url: ' + axiosOptions.url +  fw_jsonFormatter(error));
            errorCallback(error);
        } else {
            console.log('fw_request_internal error-2 method: ' + axiosOptions.method + ' url: ' + axiosOptions.url);
            console.log(fw_jsonFormatter(error));
        }
    });
}

function fw_jsonFormatter(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 1);
}

function fw_test_end_wait(done, msg, waitSecs) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Waited ' + waitSecs + ' seconds');
        console.log(msg);
        done();}, waitSecs * 1000);
}
```